# Send context with Django class based LisView per item

Tags: django

In Django class based ListView I send the list of items with their details, I also want to send `True` \ `False` or `0\1` whether this item is in the user bookmark list or not after checking if user `id` is in favorites (ManyToManyField) field of object.

```
if query_set['posts'][i].favorites.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
   # send True
else:
   # send False
```

In template I want to do one thing if it is true and another different thing if it is false.

```
{% if True %}
... # This means that this item has already been bookmarked.
{% else %}
... # This means that this item has not been bookmarked before.
{% endif %}
```

My `ListView`:

```
class PostsListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'user_post_list.html'
    model = Post
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        query_set = super(PostsListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        program = UserExtra.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).values('program')[0]['program']
        if program == 'Post':
            query_set['posts'] = Post.objects.filter(query1)
            is_favorite = False
            for i in range(0, len(query_set['posts'])):
                if query_set['posts'][i].favorites.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
                    is_favorite = True
                else:
                    is_favorite = False
        if program == 'Send':
            query_set['sends'] = Post.objects.filter(query2)
            is_favorite = False
            for i in range(0, len(query_set['sends'])):
                if query_set['sends'][i].favorites.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
                    is_favorite = True
                else:
                    is_favorite = False
        elif ...:
            .... 
        return query_set
```

Comment: Can you share the full `ListView`, it looks rather odd that you work with a `query_set['posts']`, etc. Especially since a `ListView` is used, well..., to render a *list* (collection) of items.

Comment: Are you trying to set one `fav` value for all the posts - as in your example for what you'd do in a function-based view - or are you trying to give each post an independent value indicating whether or not it's a favorite?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper One for each item. `fav` means if user has already added that item to her favorites list or not.

Answer (score 0):

After a day, I found the solution:
In `views.py`:

```
if query_set['posts'][i].favorites.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
   query_set['posts'][i].is_favorite = True
else:
   query_set['posts'][i].is_favorite = False
```

and in template:

```
{% for object in posts %}

{% if object.is_favorite == True %}
 # Anything that should be executed if is_favorite is True.
{% else %}
 # Anything that should be executed if is_favorite is False.

{% endif %}
```